# Globe projection with zoom and rotate only

Tags: d3.js, projection

I am having toruble with the D3 globe projection. If I add zoom but do not transform the globe on zoom, the globe zooms into the top left corner of the svg container. If I add translate on zoom, so that it zooms into the center, the rotate stops working, because it conflicts with the zoom translate.

I tried removing rotation and it works fine, however I need to have the globe rotating aswell. Is there any way to fix the globe so that the translate only works with zoom and does not translate the globe on rotation.

For zooming I use the following code:

```
  var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .scale(scale0)
    .scaleExtent([scale0, 8 * scale0])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);
```

and for the rotation on drag:

```
.call(d3.behavior.drag()
  .origin(function() { var r = projection.rotate(); return {x: r[0] / sens, y: -r[1] / sens}; })
  .on("drag", function() {
    var rotate = projection.rotate();
    projection.rotate([d3.event.x * sens, -d3.event.y * sens, rotate[2]]);
    svg.selectAll("path.land").attr("d", path);
    svg.selectAll(".focused").classed("focused", focused = false);
  }))
```

The codepen is located here: https://codepen.io/kvyb/pen/vdmxBe

I tried to compensate by making the drag stronger than the translate by increasing sensitivity, but that seems to be a very bad solution.

Any tips on achieving a steady globe with the functionality in the post title?

Comment: Not sure I follow, [here I've commented out the translate](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bLRWmp?editors=0010) in the `zoomed` callback.  It now rotates and zooms and I don't see it move to the corner.

Comment: ugh oh. It seems I was commenting out the wrong translate.